# Mule Dataweave: Need to extract values from an array

Tags: mule, dataweave

Added new code, where I am trying to first save the lineData, processing header and coming back to line, however it is not liking the setPayloadToLines

```
 <set-variable variableName="lineData" value="#[payload.LineID]" doc:name="Variable"/>
  …              

 <set-payload value="lineData" doc:name="setPayloadToLines" />
 <foreach doc:name="For Each" collection="#[payload.LineID]">
    <db:insert config-ref="Oracle_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[INSERT INTO HDR_TABLE (LINE_ID,ID) VALUES(LINE_SEQ.NEXTVAL,#[payload.LineID])]]></db:parameterized-query>
    </db:insert>
    </foreach>
```

Comment: Do you want each comma separated value to be an input in DB?

Comment: Yes that is true .. I want to insert as a seperate row into DB table.

Comment: Is dataweave required? I can show you an easy way

Comment: I am ok with getting rid of dataweave. by the way the complete payload looks like this ..                        {id=A0YAAW, LineID=[9Ej6EAE, 9EjGEAU, 9EjBEAU], name=Test 2.24, startDate=2017-02-17, ...}

Comment: The Line ID I want to put in one table & remaining values in another

Comment: That is not a json and then you don't need json to object transformer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ou haven't shown your full json request, let's consider you have following json:-

```
{
    "Industry": ["111","ggh","ooo",888],
    "Phone": null,
    "Id": null,
    "type": "Account",
    "Name": "Manufacturing"
}
```

So here is how ou can extract each comma separate value and insert it into db:-

```
 <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <flow name="TestFlow" >
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="#[payload.Industry]"/>
        <foreach doc:name="For Each" collection="#[payload.Industry]">
            <logger message="Each extracted value :#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            <!-- Your Database insert code here inserting each value with #[payload] -->
        </foreach>
        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
   </flow>
```

You can modify this above code and use it to insert into db.
pls note inside for loop `#[payload]` has extracted comma separated value. You can put it into a variable if you want and use it instead of writting `#[payload]`

**UPDATE:**

As per you question, I have updated your query:-

```
<foreach doc:name="For Each" collection="#[payload.LineID]">
    <db:insert config-ref="Oracle_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[INSERT INTO HDR_TABLE (ID,LINE_ID) VALUES(LINE_SEQ.NEXTVAL,#[payload])]]></db:parameterized-query>
    </db:insert>
```

Comment: Is there anyway of optimizing with 'Bulk Insert' into DB & optimize on the foreach?

Comment: Give me a few I am testing it out

Comment: Anirban I added the modified code as per your directions, can you let me know your thoughts?

Comment: Are you able to insert into db ?

Comment: The header goes through but the lineData does not

Comment: in the log I see the following: org.mule.routing.ExpressionSplitter: Splitter returned no results. If this is not expected, please check your split expression

Comment: pls check the example I have given ... It would  be #[payload] and not #[payload.LineID] in db insert

Comment: Made the change, but do you see issues with the way I am saving the 'lineData' variable & later referencing it to insert into a DB?

Comment: You are doing wrong .. why are you setting the payload before for each ??? it is replacing the payload ...

Comment: pls dont set any payload before for each, don't set any variable.. try the way I have shown you in my updated answer , you will able to insert it into db .. If you face issue update your question with the latest flow

Comment: Anirban, before I call this flow I am calling a dataweave transform that modifies the value for the header table & does an insert, & that is why I was saving the lineData in a flow Variable so that I can use it later as per your technique to insert into the line table (given that line data has an array in it), that is why I was replacing the payload as correct if I am wrong the transformation before is going to modify the payload correct?